# Cannot import models from another app in Django

Tags: python, django, django-apps

so I have 2 apps running in the same project.

My files are structured as follows:

```
/project_codebase
    /project
        __init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
        ...    
    /app1
        ...
    /app2
        ...
    manage.py
```

So, I for some weird reason have a different name for my base directory (that is, it ends with codebase). Hopefully, that is not an issue.

In my **settings.py**, I have this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'app1',
    'app2',
]
```

Ok, so in my **models.py (from app2)**, I can easily import models from app1 with `from app1.models import *`, however, when I use `from app2.models import *` in my **models.py (from app1)**, I get an ImportError.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: May be it is due to circular dependency. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: Well, you've created a circular import dependency. Why do you need to import each app's models into the other?

Comment: You should accept an answer.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This might be due to **circular import** issues. To avoid this you should **load the model dynamically**:

For **recent versions of django (1.7+)** use the [application registry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#module-django.apps):

```
from django.apps import apps
MyModel1 = apps.get_model('app1', 'MyModel1')
```

For **earlier django versions (<1.7)**:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
MyModel1 = get_model('app1', 'MyModel1')
```

**Note 1:** If you want to define a **ForeignKey relationship**, there is **no need for a separate import statement**. Django [has you covered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) on this:

If `app1` is an installed app, you should define the ForeignKey relationship as follows:

```
# in app2.py
class MyModel2(models.Model):
   mymodel1 = models.ForeignKey('app1.MyModel1')
```

**Note 2**: The `get_model` only works if `app1` is an installed app and `MyModel1` is the model you want to import from `app1`.

**Note 3:** Try to avoid wildcard import (`from ... import *`), as [this is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615206/1622937).

Comment: Why django switched to that kind of import. Previously we used to import models as "import"

Comment: @ilyasJumadurdyew this is mainly to avoid circular imports that would happen when the modules are loaded using the 'traditional' `import` statement. Using `get_model` or the above shown foreignkey definition imports the models on runtime only, once all modules are loaded.

Comment: "Note 1" will help someone cross-linking models in Django with this a non-descriptive exception: RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")!

Answer (score 11):

It's definitely a circular import.

But i think is what you need is to use models as some sort of RetationFields(`ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField` or `OneToOneField`) arguments. So you need to skip import and use as so:

```
# app1/models.py
class Model1(models.Model):
    relation_field = models.ForeignKey('app2.Model2')
```

From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> If you need to create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself
>
> To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly specify a model with the full application label

Just put `str` object as first argument to relation fields that leeds to `<app_name>.<Model_name>`.

**Note**: it's better to avoid importing everything from module(`from <module_name> import *`)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to import only some specific module then do not use `import *`.

It will take more time load your all library and so can affect the speed of your app also.

If you want to use few modules from your second app then just add module name instead of whole libraries something like this:

```
from app2.models import Module1, Module2
```

or it may be circular import issue as other clarify.

Thanks.

Comment: beautiful - this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

i use this code always and it's work :)

`from position_app.models import Member`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the model names you want to import, for ex `from app1.models import ModelName1, ModelName2`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no name clash between one of your apps and one of the modules installed in your Python environment. If you use pip, you can run `pip freeze`to see a list of installed modules.

I had the same error when one of my apps was named 'packaging', and the packaging python module was installed.

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem when I try to import my model from another app in (django2.2)

But at last I Imported It and Its successfully working.

here is my two app:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...

    'categories',
    'videos',
]
```

and this is the code for how I Imported it into **videos/models.py** file as a **ForeignKey** Connectivity

```
from django.db import models

class Videos(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey('categories.Categories', related_name='categories', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If want to see my Categories Model from **categories/models.py** file, you can check this code otherwise neglect it

```
from django.db import models

class Categories(models.Model): 
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a circular import

In my case I needed the imported class not for a relation field, but for use it inside a method instead.
If that's the case, I suggest to import inside the method, otherwise an AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.") is raised.

```
class Student(CustomUser):
""" Usuario alumno """
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Alumno"
    verbose_name_plural = "Alumnos"

def get_current_school_class(self):
    """ Obtiene el curso actual de un alumno """
    from school.models import SchoolClass, StudentClass
    # proceed with the method...
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not necessary to import models from others apps
just put the app.models in the foreignkey field and that's work ;)

**app 1**:

```
class model1(models.Model):
    field=models.field type ...
```

**app 2**:

```
class model2(models.Model):
    field=models.ForeignKey('app1.model1', on_delete. ...)
```

to avoid code correction :D

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you are about to answer an old question (this one is over 3 years old) that already has an accepted answer (that is the case here) please ask yourself: Do I really have a substantial improvement to offer? If not, consider refraining from answering.