# Any better way to queryset objects from one app to another in wagtail/django?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a **home** app with `HomePage` model which gets object from `BlogPage` model in **blog** app. I use this code below the obtain the object from `BlogPage` to `HomePage`.

**blog app**

```py
class HomePage(Page):
    primary_header = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,)
    secondary_header = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,)
    hero_banner_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', 
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name='+')

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # Get object from Blog Page
        blogpages = self.get_children().get(title='Blog Page').get_children().live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context
```

I used `get()` to obtain the object by title, but I feel that it may not be the best way to do it. If I were to rename the `BlogPage` title field to for example, "The Blog Page", it will break the code since 'Blog Page' is no more used. Is there a better way to queryset from `BlogPage` to `HomePage` model?

**home app**

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    subpage_types = ['PostPage']

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        category_slug = request.GET.get('category', None)
        context['categories'] = BlogCategory.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your `HomePage` will only ever have one child of type `BlogPage` you can use the Wagtail `PageQuerySet` `exact_type` query.

```py
blog_index_page = self.get_children().exact_type(BlogPage).first()
blog_pages = blog_index_page.get_children().live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')
```

- Django queryset `first` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#first
- type - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet.type
- exact_type - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet.exact_type

If you are having trouble importing the model from another app, you can work around this with `apps.get_model` which is part of `django.apps`.

Note: You may need to do this import within your `get_context` to avoid circular import issues.

```py
from django.apps import apps

MyModel1 = apps.get_model('app1', 'MyModel1')
```

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_model
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43847288/8070948

Comment: Thanks alot for the helpful response. When I used your code `blog_pages = self.get_children().exact_type(BlogPage).get_children().live().public().order_by('-first_published_at')`, I got an AttributeError as the `exact_type()` method outputs an object. The `get_children()` is not attribute of an object. So I sliced the first value in the object with this `blog_pages = self.get_children().exact_type(BlogPage)[0].get_children().live().public().order_by('-first_published_at'`. Not sure if thats the right way to do it, but it worked.

Comment: @Heroo - fixed it up based on your comments, what you did is correct, Django will treat slice `[0]` in a similar way to `first()` but `first()` will give you back `None` if no value is found but slide will throw an error.